# How do I pass data from an ASP.NET WebAPI ApiController to an ASP.NET MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have the following method in my ASP.NET Web API controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string code1, string code2)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("/", UriKind.Relative);

    return response;
}
```

I'd like to take the values passed in for code1 and code2 and make them available to an MVC Controller (based on the redirect above, let's just assume it's the HomeController). What is the best way to do this?

A few considerations:

- I'm not calling the WebAPI. A 3rd party site calls the endpoint and passes along code1 and code2 (it's part of an OAuth dance and is the reason I use the redirect).
- One of the values will be an access token used later for authentication. (Yes, this would eventually use HTTPS.)
- I'd like a method that's flexible enough to pass one or more values back to the MVC Controller.
- I do not necessarily need the data to live passed the session.

Thanks!

**Update:** Here's a look at the final code and approach.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string display, string code)
{
    var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
    await auth.WebServer(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret, _callbackUrl, code);

    var url = string.Format("/?token={0}&api={1}&instance_url={2}", auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion,
        auth.InstanceUrl);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Just use `HttpClient` in your MVC controller to call your Web API controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @ChrisHardie! One thing I didn't mention (I will update) is that it's not my MVC Controller calling the WebAPI - it's a 3rd party site that's calling my WebAPI and passing these values along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you have much choice other than to use a query string parameter.  Path parameters don't really make much sense as there is no natural hierarchy with an auth token.

Comment: Thanks Darrel! I figured it would come to this but was hoping that there was something in the framework that better managed passing data from an ApiController to a Controller. Seems like it would be a common use case?

Comment: @Wade But with a redirect, you are going back to the client and HTTP is stateless.  Do you want avoid going back to the client? To ask that a different way, would it be ok to return the MVC Controller result back from the API method?

Comment: No, I definitely want to go back to the client.

Comment: @Wade, ok, so then you can't make the assumption that there will be an MVC controller at the end of the URI.  Today that may be the case, but next week it could be a NancyFX module.  You don't want to couple the the implementation technology of a redirect source and target.

Comment: MVC and Web API are two different frameworks with two different runtimes, so you don't have an easy way to pass values between them. I guess you want to do something like a server transfer, but I don't think it is possible. If MVC is a requirement, I would implement everything o that side

Comment: Thanks Darrel. Good points.

@PabloCibraro You also raise a good point. I could easily implement both in an MVC Controller.

Comment: I've decided to go with this approach. Thanks guys!